# Vertical graphing in Dygraph?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'd like to use Dygraphs for a web project, but I need to graph my lines in a "vertical" fashion- meaning- what is normally the X axis (horizontally, along the bottom), I need to be graphed from top to bottom (with the x axis along the left edge).

I've looked at several graphing libraries for this and none seem to support it. I recently discovered Dygraphs so I'm hoping it might have this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While vertical charts are not supported out of the box, it is possible to achieve this effect using CSS transformations. Basically, you rotate the `<div>` that contains the chart by 90 degrees and undo that transformation for the labels.

One dygraphs user was able to get this work. See [this demo](http://www.ransomchristofferson.com/flipped_dygraph/).

Comment: I have one more dygraph question here, appreciate any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612516/more-than-2-y-axis-in-dygraphs

Answer (score 0):

The css to rotate the graph:

```
.graphStyle {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(280px,240px);
}
.dygraph-axis-label.dygraph-axis-label-x {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-20px, 0);
}
.dygraph-axis-label.dygraph-axis-label-y {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-10px,10px);
}

.dygraph-legend {
  transform: translate(-320px,-300px) rotate(-90deg);}
```

The translations were to place the graph where I wanted, you will have to change them.

Comment: Is it possible to rotate selections as well?

Comment: That i can't answer