# more than 2 y axis in dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Looking through the documentation, I haven't been able to determine if Dygraphs can support more than 2 y axis on the graph outputs? I need to graph a lot of curves with many different axis ranges.

Comment: edited question- it can support more than 2 lines. But I still don't know if it can draw more than 2 y axis (ie, if I have 3 lines that need different scales, can I stack multiple y axis to show these ranges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be possible. [This example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/value-axis-formatters.html) seems to be using it by using `axes` and some other options (`'labelName': { axis: {} }` seems to create another Y-axis), altho I haven't found it in the docs.

But when trying to use more than two Y-axes I saw this message in the log:

```
dygraphs: Only two y-axes are supported at this time. (Trying to use 3) (stacktrace.js:31:25)
```

Code from the example:

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("demodiv"),
    data, {
        labels: ['Date', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4'],
        width: 640,
        height: 350,
        'Y3': {
            axis: {}
        },
        'Y4': {
            axis: 'Y3' // use the same y-axis as series Y3
        },
        xAxisLabelWidth: 100,
        yAxisLabelWidth: 100,
        axes: {
            x: {
                valueFormatter: function(ms) {
                    return 'xvf(' + new Date(ms).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ')';
                },
                axisLabelFormatter: function(d) {
                    return 'xalf(' + d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ')';
                },
                pixelsPerLabel: 100,
            },
            y: {
                valueFormatter: function(y) {
                    return 'yvf(' + y.toPrecision(2) + ')';
                },
                axisLabelFormatter: function(y) {
                    return 'yalf(' + y.toPrecision(2) + ')';
                }
            },
            y2: {
                valueFormatter: function(y2) {
                    return 'y2vf(' + y2.toPrecision(2) + ')';
                },
                axisLabelFormatter: function(y2) {
                    return 'y2alf(' + y2.toPrecision(2) + ')';
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: correct, that example shows how to use 2, but I need more than two. so it sounds like your test proves it can currently only support up to 2.

Comment: @boomhauer, I'm looking around for a JS time series chart lib. Flot seemed nice, but it's missing some features I'd like to have (like Highcharts stock easy navigation with its small navigator series), and it doesn't seem that developed lately. Now looking closer at D3, or something D3 based. [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) seems to come close to what I'd want.